# how to clear input in bash

Tags: bash, flush

I am making a script which read an answer after a task and then write it in a textfile. I want this answer to be just one character :

```
task1
read -n 1 answer < /dev/tty
echo $answer >> result.txt
task2
read -n 1 answer < /dev/tty
echo $answer >> result.txt
```

Problem is, if I accidently press twice the keyboard, the 2nd character remains in the memory and write it as the next answer.

I'd like to insert a command which flush the memory after the first character is written in file.txt
thanks

Comment: There is no need to specify "</dev/tty". By default, read wait for the input from command line.

Comment: The task I am doing redirect the standard input. I agree it's not necessary in this post, I should have removed it

Comment: The problem is that the shell never reads directly from the keyboard; it reads from a file, and it can't control what gets written to that file. Your terminal emulator is the place where this behavior needs to be configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to capture the answer, you need to establish a delay to identify what is an accidental pressing. So, after you read the first character, you can use `read -e -t2` to discard any key press within 2 seconds.

```
task1
read -n 1 answer 
echo $answer >> result.txt
read -e -t2 #Discard additional input within 2 seconds.
task2
read -n 1 answer 
echo $answer >> result.txt
read -e -t2 #Discard additional input within 2 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `read` that will swallow the line upto the next cariage return.

```
task1
read -n 1 answer
echo $answer >> result.txt
read
task2
read -n 1 answer
echo $answer >> result.txt
read
```

Comment: I'd like my script to continue automatically to the next line after "read -n 1 answer". If I add another read I have to press enter to continue, if I add "read -n 1" it won't continue either if I only press once

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
task 1
read  first
answer=`cut -b1 <<<$first`
echo $answer >> result.txt

task 2
read second
answer=`cut -b1 <<<$second`
echo $answer >> result.txt
```

There is not way to flush the input buffer in shell.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
{
  original_terminal_state="$(stty -g)"
  stty -icanon -echo min 0 time 0
  LC_ALL=C dd bs=1 > /dev/null 2>&1
  stty "$original_terminal_state"
} < /dev/tty
```